# How can I order only some specific objects randomly in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model with `is_random_sortable` boolean field and `position` integer field, I want to sort queryset randomly when `is_random_sortable` is true, otherwise, I want to order by `position` field.

Imagine I have an object with `is_random_sortable=False` and position=3. I want to have sorted results like this:

(numbers are positions)

[15, 6, 9, 3, 11, 7, 10,...]

object with position 3 always is on index 3 of the list. And other objects with `is_random_sortable=True` are sorted randomly.

Comment: Does this mean the items with `is_random_sortable`set to `False` are first in the list? What value does `position` have if the `is_random_sortable` is?

Comment: what do you mean by "sort randomly"?

Comment: something like Model.objects.order_by("?")
@MohitC

Comment: I think you should try with CASE in orm and then sort the queryset based on the conditions.